# JavaFX WebView URL.createObjectURL undefined

Tags: java, javascript, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I'm using JavaFX 8 embedded WebView. I want to build Blob URL from an Blob image. But, URL.createObjectURL gives me undefined. Is there any way (shim or eg.) to create Blob URL from Blob object in JavaFX 8 WebView environment??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not currently supported, but will be once Java 9 comes out, in September.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148114

Comment: If you wish, you could download an [early access build of Java 9](https://jdk9.java.net/download/) and see if it works as expected.